# Force a div to the end of a text node

Tags: html, css, flexbox

We have html that is generated by a third-party which is periodically updated so a javascript solution won't do.

Here is an example of the generated html:

```html
<div class="label">
  <div class="asterisk">*</div>
  I am a text node
</div>
```

Which (without css) renders like:

[image: no style render]

I'm trying to align the asterisk to the end of the text node which I've achieved with the below css...

```css
.label {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Result:

[image: current css render]

However, the problem occurs when the text node wraps onto the next line...

[image: wrapping issue]

Desired result...

[image: desired result]

---

**Update**

Adding `align-items: flex-end;` is a closer result!

[image]

---

**Update 2**

From @OMi Shah's comment adding `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;` is close but not quite there...

[image]

Comment: Can you wrap the text "Im a text node" in an element?

Comment: @LinkinTED sadly not, we have no control over the DOM in this case

Comment: add ``flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;`` and it should work as intended.

Comment: @OMiShah please see Update 2

Comment: You can't do this with css alone unless you changed the structure of your html.  Unless you have a class on one of the parents that denotes that label is required - then you could hide the asterisk and add a pseudo element with an asterisk in your labels after

Answer (score 1):

Add a `align-self` to the `.asteriks`

```css
.label {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  
  margin-bottom: 2em; /* only for demo */
}
.asterisk { align-self: flex-end }
```

```html
<div class="label">
  <div class="asterisk">*</div>
  I am a text node
</div>

<div class="label">
  <div class="asterisk">*</div>
  I am a <br />
  text node
</div>

<div class="label">
  <div class="asterisk">*</div>
  I am<br />
  a <br />
  text <br />
  node
</div>
```

Comment: Love it! However, I'm unable to add `<br>`'s to the DOM. If you changed the width of label (e.g. add `max-width: 50px`) you'll see this doesn't quire work.

Comment: wouldn't work if you had I am a text on one line and then node and the asterisk on another

Comment: Ah, damn. I only added the `br` to show it "workes". But you are right, with a width is doesn't fully work. It's too bad you can't wrap the text in an element, because then the answer would be simple :)

Comment: @LinkinTED tell me about it! Would love to modify change the structure, it would solve so many headaches!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dequ6mrh/

Answer (score 0):

For those browsers that support CSS :has (which is Chrome/Edge/Safari but Firefox requires a setting) this snippet seems to work:

Abandon ideas of trying to get that asterisk in the div into the right place and instead get rid of it and set the asterisk in an after pseudo element.

This snippet has a large font size so it's easier to test the width getting smaller:

```css
div.label {
  font-size: 76px;
}

div.label:has(.asterisk)::after {
  content: '*';
}

div.label div.asterisk {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="label">
  <div class="asterisk">*</div>
  I am a text node
</div>
```